# Unable to locate package ros-lunar-desktop-full

Tags: apt

I have this ubuntu:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:    17.10
Codename:   artful
```

I have followed everything from the page [Ubuntu install of ROS Lunar](http://wiki.ros.org/lunar/Installation/Ubuntu).

I did everything on this page, but when I do:

> sudo apt-get install ros-lunar-desktop-full

I get the following message:

```
Unable to locate package ros-lunar-desktop-full
```

Is there something I can check to find why it isn't finding the package?

`apt update` returns:

```
Reading list of packages ... Done
W: chmod 0700 of directory / var / lib / apt / lists / partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not allowed)
E: Could not open the lock file "/ var / lib / apt / lists / lock" - open (13: Permission denied)
E: The / var / lib / apt / lists / directory could not be blocked
W: There was a problem in unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission Denied)
W: There was a problem in unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission Denied)
```

Comment: Try: ``apt-cache search ros-lunar``.  If that fails with no hits,  you probably have an mistake in your repository specification.  Please post the output of ``apt update``.

Comment: @MartinW `apt-cache search ros-lunar ` returns 227 lines.

Comment: @MartinW I have updated the question with the `apt update` output.

Comment: The problem with your apt-update is a separate issue.  Looks like you may have aborted an apt command and left a lock file.   You may need to delete  that manually, after making sure that there is no apt command currently running using ``sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ros does not support Lunar for artful (17.10), see [the Ros wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/lunar). I believe that you are out of luck, at least without a bunch of personal work or reverting to a zesty (17.04) install. You might try compiling and installing from source but since they are not supporting 17.10, your luck may very, and people trying this have had trouble.

Comment: Thanks. Melodic Morenia will support Ubuntu 17.10 and 18.04.